# Как в git переименовать файл gitignore.txt в .gitignore?

Tags: git

Использовала команду `git mv file_oldName file_newName`(и еще эту команду `ren gitignore.txt .gitignore`, хотя git выдает что 'ren' is not a git command.). Не сработало. Везде информация про причины не игнорирования содержимое .gitignore, но очень мало информации про то как именно создать этот файл(.gitignore). Мне не надо что там записать что игнорировать(это я знаю), **мне важно как именно создать этот файл?** **В папке проекта надо создать(внутри папки src или вне src или в другом месте)?** **И после запускании команды** `git init` **надо переименовать этот файл или до запускания этой команды?(но думаю точно надо переименовать до команды git add)**

Comment: По-моему, нужен файл именно с таким расширением `.gitignore`, поэтому попробуйте создать `git.gitignore`, т.е. базовое название файла `git` (оно может быть любым) и расширение `.gitignore`

Comment: Windows? (Еще 6 букв)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**.gitignore** можно создавать на любом этапе проекта. В идеале с самого начала. Но по факту, как получится. Можно создавать не один такой файл, а по каждому файлу на директорию, если есть на то необходимость. Общая практика один файл в корне проекта.

> git выдает что 'ren' is not a git command

И правильно ругается. Ведь **ren** действительно не команда GIT-а -- это виндовая команда.

---

Для того, что бы создать .gitignore в Windows необходимо:

1. Создать текстовый файл gitignore.txt
2. Открываем его любым txt редактором.
3. Можно сразу добавить необходимые правила и сохранить.
4. Теперь необходимо переименовать файл. Зажмите Shift, затем ПКМ, (внутри папки с gitignore.txt) в контекстом меню выбираем "Открыть окно команд" (Точность названия пункта в контекстом меню не гарантирую ибо сам сижу на Linux)
5. ren gitignore.txt .gitignore

---

***P.S.*** Есть ещё один простой способ на случай если вот вообще нифига не получается - архих. Создаёте пустой rar архив там же где и нужный файл, открываете его (архив), получаете "проводник". Через него находите нужный файл и переименовываете прямо в rar. Готово

Comment: Спасибо большое. И в Windows 4-ый пункт такой.

Answer (score 2):

Если правильно понимаю вопрос, файл `.gitignore` создаете любым удобным способом (командная строка, файловый менеджер, текстовый редактор). В названии файла нет расширения, а начинается с точки.

Про расположение: файлов игнора может быть несколько в иерархии вашего репозитория (например сабмодули могут содержать свои вложенные `.gitignore` файлы, вложенные папки также могут подчиняться более строгому набору правил), в таком случае происходит наследование игноров от родительской папки к дочерней.
Но обычно `.gitignore` располагается в корневом каталоге репозитория, на одном уровне с директорией `.git`. Вы можете его добавить и до `git init` и после, это не имеет значения. В любом случае вы этот файл должны добавить в репозиторий командой `git add`

Comment: Я данный момент делаю как по видео https://youtu.be/EjRQ8qccLCQ. Там создали файл с именем .gitignore на Notepad++(текстовый редактор). Потом удалили расширение txt. А я создала на обычном текстовом редакторе(Блокнот). А потом не получается удалить это расширение txt. Как удалить этот расширение txt?

Comment: Если не получается в файловом менеджере, попробуйте через ком строку. Например `rename ".gitignore.txt" ".gitignore"`. Также можете пересохранить файл в текстовом редакторе без указания расширения

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы под проводником Windows создать файл без имени, но с расширением, необходимо назвать его следующим образом: `.gitignore.`

При завершении переименовывания точка в конце не будет учитываться, и именем файла будет просто `.gitignore`.